# Jquery with Meteor only works on first Element

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a Template Helper that I can't get to work on anything other than the first element. On the first element everything works exactly as expected.

```
Template.placecardsnot.events({
    'change .browser-default': function(event) {
        var selectedTable = $('.tablesassignments :selected').val();
        var table = tables.findOne(selectedTable);
        console.log(table.description);
        placecards.update(this._id, {
            $set: {      
                newtable: selectedTable, table: table.description
            }
        });
    }
});
```

How can I use the .each in this template? I can't seem to get the Meteor Jquery situation right.

My HTML Looks like this:

```
<template name="placecardsnot">
      {{#each placecardnotassigned}}
             <b> {{name}} </b>
               <select class="browser-default tablesassignments" id="{{_id}}">
                    <option value="">Assign Table</option>
                    {{> tablenotassigned }}
               </select>
     {{/each}}  
</template>
```

I have a second template which generates the dropdown options for each select choice.

```
<template name="tablenotassigned">
{{#each table}}
<option class="optionvalue" value="{{_id}}">{{description}}</option>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

All said and done, I have about 20 dropdown choices and having the same class, each with a unique ID (which comes from the collection). When I try and change the second one

Comment: could you elaborate? It's not clear to me what you mean by "other than the first element". What/where is the list, and how do you create it?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I apologize for that, I just updated it with the other code to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work. Your jquery selector will always pick the first element. You need to use your `event.target` to first find the sub-tree in the DOM of your current element. Try this:

```
    var selectedTable = $(even.target).find('.tablesassignments :selected').val();
```

Or you could restructure your template and have a separate template for the body of the `each`. Then you can attach the event handler to that template and simply use

```
    var selectedTable = this.$('.tablesassignments :selected').val();
```

Comment: thanks however this still keeps showing undefined when I log it to the console. I tried many different variations and none of them worked. For example: 'var selectedTable = $(".tablesassignments :selected", this);' this prints out the parent object. And 'var selectedTable1 = $('.tablesassignments :selected').val();' this prints out what ever the first element currently has selected, it doesn't seem to find the currently selected element.